Connecting logic analyzer to PC and a device with another power source
I have a device that gets the power signal of 12 V but the 2 data pins that I want to measure are 5 V.
Is it safe to connect a logic analyzer to my PC while measuring Wiegand signals generated by a device powered by 12 V (is powered by converting AC grid power to 12 V DC), considering the signals I want to measure range from 0-5 V. I have connected the GND of the logic analyzer to the GND of the device.
I have connected the GND of the device to the logic analyzer,
but does the fact that the logic analyzer gets the power from the USB that is a different power source from the power source of device create a problem even though the ground are connected they have common ground?

It would be great if you listed what logic analyzer you are using.

Hi @vini_i , I thinks my version is this one https://www.amazon.in/Analyzer-Device-Ferrite-Channel-Arduino/dp/B099WJQV67

What's your question and can you describe your problem?

Hi @Colin My question is :
Is it safe to connect a logic analyzer to my PC while measuring Wiegand signals generated by a device powered by 12V ( is powered by converting AC grid power to 12V DC ), considering the signals I want to measure range from 0 to 5V .
I have connected the GND of the logic analyzer to the GND of the device .

@user466575 the question belongs in the question section at the top of this page ... it does not belong in a comment ... please update your question


does the fact that the logic analyzer gets the power from the usb that is a different power source from the power source of device create a problem

No, there's no problem, as long as the grounds are connected.
